# Django / DRF: Filter Reverse Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'd like to be able to filter on the relationship ONLY of a Django Model.

Here's what the models look like:

```
Identity(models.Model):
    username = model.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True)

PaymentSource(models.Model):
    identity = models.ForeignKey(
        'identity.identity',
        related_name='payment_sources',
        on_delete='CASCADE',
        blank=True,
    )
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

There's also complete serializer code for both. With Identity referencing the `PaymentSerializer`.

How would I get an Identity serializer with DRF to pass back as a response, without including any `PaymentSource` models in the foreign key if `deleted_at` is not None?

The cases broken down:

```
1) There should only be 1 Identity object returned

2) If there are many payment sources with deleted_at set as None, then they should be shown within the Identity.payment_sources

3) If there are none, Identity should still be returned. However an empty list should be returned from Identity.payment_sources
```

Comment: You need to modify your serializer. Please your code and we can try to tell you how. If you need sometimes all your payment sources and other times on the ones with deleted_at, then you will need two serializers but unclear if that is what you want

Comment: You could override `to_internal_value` and `to_representation` methods of ModelSerializer to achieve this.